# Div container doesn't change color attribute on hover

Tags: html, css

This is my first post on stack overflow so I'll make this simple.

I have [this little page](http://codepen.io/polybox/pen/ALEvx) that I am making for my IT class and I'm having quite a problem.

```
.float1 {
    float:right;
    background-color:#A3635C;
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    transition: 1s;
}

.float1:hover {
    background-color:white;
    color:#A3635C;
}
```

The second container square (red background) doesn't change to `color: #A3635C;` on hover.
The text remains white.

Maybe someone knows how to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: your paragraph tag inside your div has the font color set to white.  It takes precedence over the styles in the class, float1.

Comment: ... specifically it is set by an `id` selector so it takes precedence over the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have color applied directly to the `<p>` element, you need to change the color using that element, not the parent element.

Right now, you have:

```
.float1:hover{background-color:white;color:#A3635C;}
```

But that wont work because the color style is applied to `#white`, not `.float1`

Change it to this:

```
.float1:hover{background-color:white;}
.float1:hover p#white {color:#A3635C;}
```

and the color will take effect.

**EDIT:** [Updated the CodePen](http://codepen.io/polybox/pen/ALEvx)

Answer (score 1):

```
#white{color:white;font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive;font-size:400%;}
```

This rule is overriding your hover color rule. Not only do your classes (.etc) have lower priority in the CSS rule-chain, but the color is being applied to an element one-up in the HTML tree (inheriting tree rules always takes the lowest-possible CSS priority)

To count up a rule's "CSS Priority":

1. Add 100 for every ID (#)
2. Add 10 for every class (.etc)
3. Add 1 for every element

Perhaps you could change "white" to be a CSS class, rather than an ID. You could also have a rule like this, or similar:

```
.float1:hover .white { color: red}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
.float1:hover #white{color:#A3635C;}
```

You have color attribute to #white and you need to override it because it will not inherit the color change from it's parent :)

You can also simplify it like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zeuAk

```
<div class="float1">
  <p>Because Color<br>Matters</p>
</div>
```

And then use the hover as it was

```
.float1:hover{background-color:white;color:#A3635C;}
```

Just add #white attributes to .float1

```
.float1 {
    color:white;
    font-family:'Lobster Two', cursive;
    font-size:400%;
    float:right;
    background-color:#A3635C;
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `#white` selector is stronger than `.float1:hover` Change to `#white:hover` or something simmilar